# I can't get the EventBus data in Fragment onCreateView

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I want to pass a value from an activity to fragment via `EventBus`. I can pass the value and read with `@Subscribe`method. But I can't pass the value to a variable at the beginning of onCreateView - setupGridView(mUser). I want to add the value `setupGridView` as a parameter. Is it possible to get EventBus data at the very beginning of `onCreateView()`?

```
private User mUser;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_pages, container, false);
  setupGridView(mUser);// mUser is null here
}

@Subscribe
public void mSetUser(User user){
  mUser = user;       
  Log.d(TAG, "mUser: " + user.toString());//I can see data here
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
  super.onDetach();
  EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Comment: pass the data through the bundle.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android

Comment: When is your `Activity` sending its event?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't pass the value to `onCreateView()` because when you're firing an Event to be received in `onCreateView()` it would be too early or too late.

Here's the explanation:

Fragment lifecycle is starting when the fragment is add to the activity. The fragment is usually added with the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Let's make the above code to a method called addExampleFragment(). So, it will be looks like this:

```
private void addExampleFragment() {
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

  ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Now, because we want the `onCreateView()` receive the **Event**, we think that we can send it before adding the Fragment with this:

```
// this is just an example of event.
// tell the subscriber about the user value.
EventBus.getDefault.post(new UserValueEvent("value");

// create the fragment
addExampleFragment()
```

But it won't work because the Fragment not yet created so it doesn't register itself as a subscriber. It's too early to send the Event.

If we want to send the Event after creating the fragment with:

```
// create the fragment
addExampleFragment()

// tell the subscriber about the user value.
EventBus.getDefault.post(new UserValueEvent("value");
```

It won't work too because `onCreateView()` is already called before the **Event** is fired. So, it's too late to send the Event.

So, you can't use Event for your `onCreateView()` problem. You can use **Bundle** instead.